# How place a library in a different memory place on an ARM microcontroller?

Tags: c, memory, arm, stm32

I would like to implement libraries at different addresses, link them dynamically and not statically to my main program. In my opinion, it can improve my FOTA update, decreasing the amount of bytes to be sent.

I thought about change it on my linker file, but I don't know how to "jump"/call the library in a different address.

Answer (score 0):

Look up bx or blx in the arm architectural reference manual that relates to your core.  (either armv6-m or armv7-m, since the instructions didn't change either will do and armv8-m uses instructions from either 6-m or 7-m (or a combination).

My guess is you are overcomplicating things and when you look at this at a system level it may not be worth the risk/effort to take this path when other less costly solutions will work, but you will want to treat this like any other loadable module, like the ones used on your computer today, be it the thing being downloaded needs functions in it called or the thing being downloaded needs to patch in functions from a library on flash, either way it works the same way you need a table of addresses in some form as complicated or as simple as you desire depending on your design.

If there is .bss or .data involved then you may need to do even more work, ideally you don't need to be position independent if you design for well known addresses, but if you don't do that then you will need to be position independent and patch up addresses accordingly making the toolchain do most of the work for you (in isolating the addresses to be changed to a set of tables that can be found).

simple example

vectors.s

```
.globl _start
_start:
.word one
.word two
.word three
```

so.c

```
unsigned int one ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(x+1);
}
unsigned int two ( unsigned int x, unsigned int y )
{
    return(x+y+2);
}
unsigned int three ( unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int z )
{
    return(z+y+z+3);
}
```

vectors.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20002000, LENGTH = 0x2000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text   : { *(.text*)   } > ram
}
```

build

```
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m0 vectors.s -o vectors.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -c so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -nostdlib -nostartfiles -T vectors.ld vectors.o so.o -o so.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.elf > so.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary so.elf so.bin
```

examine

```
Disassembly of section .text:

20002000 <_start>:
20002000:   2000200d    andcs   r2, r0, sp
20002004:   20002011    andcs   r2, r0, r1, lsl r0
20002008:   20002019    andcs   r2, r0, r9, lsl r0

2000200c <one>:
2000200c:   3001        adds    r0, #1
2000200e:   4770        bx  lr

20002010 <two>:
20002010:   3102        adds    r1, #2
20002012:   1808        adds    r0, r1, r0
20002014:   4770        bx  lr
20002016:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)

20002018 <three>:
20002018:   3103        adds    r1, #3
2000201a:   0052        lsls    r2, r2, #1
2000201c:   1888        adds    r0, r1, r2
2000201e:   4770        bx  lr
```

then you can use this either doing the function pointer thing or a helper function

using blx

```
.globl bounce
bounce:
    push {r3,lr}
    ldr r0,[r0]
    blx r0
    pop {r3,pc}
```

but that is unecessary can just use bx

```
.globl bounce
bounce:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx r0

...

unsigned int bounce ( unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int );
...
ret=bounce(0x20002000,17,0,0); // one(17);
ret=bounce(0x20002004,11,13,0); // two(11,13);
ret=bounce(0x20002008,1,2,3); // three(1,2,3);
...
```

Yes, this example was designed to work you also have to know the calling convention and if you use more than r0-r3 for parameters more work has to be done.  or you can have a bounce function per library function or a set of them or whatever.

You have to be real careful with C function pointer approach because they can fail with the cortex-m and you cant insure from C that they will work it depends on the rest of the function and some other factors how the code gets implemented (other SO questions and answers on this topic).  It has to do with having the lsbit set for thumb.  Which you can see how I did it here I didn't need to mess with that I could have orred in a 1 in the bounce function for paranoia reasons, I would not use add because as you see here if I ORed that would still work if I used ADD then it would crash if the linker did the work for me.

Short answer just look up bx and blx those are the key to branching/calling with respect to your question.  You should have a copy of the arm technical reference manual for the core you are using and a copy of the arm architectural reference manual for the architecture used by that core when doing this kind of work, as well as the datasheet and reference manual for the part in question.  (The ARM ARM contains the instruction set information for that architecture).

Answer (score 0):

It looks complicated but it is actually quite simple.

1. Rename the `.text` segments in your library linker script (the names have to be distinct from your main app ones)
2. Change the load addresses of those segments to the ones you need
3. Link statically with your app
4. Save your binary file from the generated .elf using objcopy and selecting the segments only from your app.
5. Enjoy

Of course the functions have to be at that addresses before you start the new app (for example be the part of the bootloader, or be placed there before the app is run).

But remember if you recompile the library and place it in the FLASH you need to relink the app.

Another way is to have the table of the function pointers at the known address. and then just call the pointer.

```
typedef struct
{
    int (*_myprintf)(const char *fmt, ...);
    FILE *(*_myfopen)(const char *pathname, const char *mode);
     /* etc etc*/
}myfuncs;

#define  fptr_start 0x8005000  // symbol defined in the linker script.

myfuncs *fptrs = (myfuncs *)fptr_start;

#define myprintf(fmt, ...) fptrs -> _myprintf(fmt, __VA_ARGS__)

void foo(int x)
{
    myprintf("%d\n", x);
}
```